# How to connect an ESP8266 device securely to a web frontend?

Tags: security, https, esp8266, esp8266wifi

I want to develop a product, a home smart thermostat which will have a web interface. The web interface would make requests to the thermostat which is controlled by an ESP8266-based wemos mini d1. And I would like to connect the frontend and the backend securely if it will be a product.

I tried making the backend to accept https requests and generated the key and cert using openssl. But when I ran the program, only the http site loaded in the browser and the https didn't (not even a 'not secure' page). I used the local ip address in the browser like this: https://192.168.1.5/

```cpp
BearSSL::ESP8266WebServerSecure server(443);
ESP8266WebServer serverHTTP(800);

void serveHomepage() {
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "Hello world https");
}

void serveHomepageHttp() {
    serverHTTP.send(200, "text/plain", "Hello world http");
}

void setup() {
    connectToWifi();

    configTime(3 * 3600, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");

    serverHTTP.on("/", serveHomepageHttp);
    serverHTTP.begin();

    server.getServer().setRSACert(new BearSSL::X509List(serverCert), new BearSSL::PrivateKey(serverKey));
    server.on("/", serveHomepage);
    server.begin();
}

void loop(){
    server.handleClient();
    serverHTTP.handleClient();
}
```

I barely found any documentation or a full demo, I followed this article: https://www.onetransistor.eu/2019/04/https-server-on-esp8266-nodemcu.html

I also read that https is relatively memory and cpu intense, so I would rather connect the esp8266  with http to a proxy/gateway server which has HTTPS support (but is not on the same network), and then that to the frontend:

Frontend -> HTTPS request to central server -> HTTP request to esp8266

I don't really know if it is secure enough, but I assume that the users that use my product have a secure home wifi and my server provider is also reliable.

So, what are my opportunities, if I want to provide my users good security with an ESP8266? Is the https proxy server mentioned above a secure enough solution?

Comment: It depends on the specific ESP8266 you have (I don't know the Wemos mini d1), but my experience with the ESP8266 Thing from SparkFun is that there just isn't enough memory for HTTPS. You need something with more memory. My recommendation is a to move to an ESP32. It's a much more capable platform for a modest cost increase. Or you can look at an ESP8266 with more memory, like the Huzzah from Adafruit. (or of course wire your own) https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=97&t=55740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible to get a secure HTTPS connection with D1 Mini and it works great:

Please try this code, insert your interface mainly in handleRoot():

```
/*
  HelloServerBearSSL - Simple HTTPS server example

  This example demonstrates a basic ESP8266WebServerSecure HTTPS server
  that can serve "/" and "/inline" and generate detailed 404 (not found)
  HTTP respoinses.  Be sure to update the SSID and PASSWORD before running
  to allow connection to your WiFi network.

  Adapted by Earle F. Philhower, III, from the HelloServer.ino example.
  This example is released into the public domain.
*/
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServerSecure.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <umm_malloc/umm_malloc.h>
#include <umm_malloc/umm_heap_select.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "your-ssid"
#define STAPSK  "your-password"
#endif

const char* ssid = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;

BearSSL::ESP8266WebServerSecure server(443);
BearSSL::ServerSessions serverCache(5);

static const char serverCert[] PROGMEM = R"EOF(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)EOF";

static const char serverKey[] PROGMEM =  R"EOF(
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
)EOF";


const int led = 13;

void handleRoot() {
  digitalWrite(led, 1);
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "Hello from esp8266 over HTTPS!");
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void handleNotFound(){
  digitalWrite(led, 1);
  String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET)?"GET":"POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<server.args(); i++){
    message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void setup(void){
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  configTime(3 * 3600, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }

  server.getServer().setRSACert(new BearSSL::X509List(serverCert), new   BearSSL::PrivateKey(serverKey));

  // Cache SSL sessions to accelerate the TLS handshake.
  server.getServer().setCache(&serverCache);

  server.on("/", handleRoot);

  server.on("/inline", [](){
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "this works as well");
  });

  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTPS server started");
}

extern "C" void stack_thunk_dump_stack();

void processKey(Print& out, int hotKey) {
  switch (hotKey) {
    case 'd': {
        HeapSelectDram ephemeral;
        umm_info(NULL, true);
        break;
      }
    case 'i': {
        HeapSelectIram ephemeral;
        umm_info(NULL, true);
        break;
      }
    case 'h': {
        {
          HeapSelectIram ephemeral;
          Serial.printf(PSTR("IRAM ESP.getFreeHeap:  %u\n"),  ESP.getFreeHeap());
        }
        {
          HeapSelectDram ephemeral;
          Serial.printf(PSTR("DRAM ESP.getFreeHeap:  %u\n"), ESP.getFreeHeap());
        }
        break;
      }
#ifdef DEBUG_ESP_PORT
    // From this context stack_thunk_dump_stack() will only work when Serial
    // debug is enabled.
    case 'p':
      out.println(F("Calling stack_thunk_dump_stack();"));
      stack_thunk_dump_stack();
      break;
#endif
    case 'R':
      out.printf_P(PSTR("Restart, ESP.restart(); ...\r\n"));
      ESP.restart();
      break;
    case '\r':
      out.println();
    case '\n':
      break;
    case '?':
      out.println();
      out.println(F("Press a key + <enter>"));
      out.println(F("  h    - Free Heap Report;"));
      out.println(F("  i    - iRAM umm_info(null, true);"));
      out.println(F("  d    - dRAM umm_info(null, true);"));
#ifdef DEBUG_ESP_PORT
      out.println(F("  p    - call stack_thunk_dump_stack();"));
#endif
      out.println(F("  R    - Restart, ESP.restart();"));
      out.println(F("  ?    - Print Help"));
      out.println();
      break;
    default:
      out.printf_P(PSTR("\"%c\" - Not an option?  / ? - help"), hotKey);
      out.println();
      processKey(out, '?');
      break;
  }
}


void loop(void){
  server.handleClient();
  MDNS.update();
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int hotKey = Serial.read();
    processKey(Serial, hotKey);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Do you know how long will it work? I would like a solution that doesn't require me to recompile the source code year to year, as I would like to build the microcontroller into a product.

Comment: Hi Mate. it depends on the SSL certification expiration date that you may check using this tool:  https://comodosslstore.com/ssltools/cert-decoder.php

Comment: According to this site, the maximum expiration date is 1 year https://blog.httpcs.com/en/ssl-certificates-maximum-validity-period-has-been-reduced-to-one-year/
However, we can generate our own certificates for longer periods of time, but the browsers will them as insecure.
You can also take a look at this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49824/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-non-expiring-ssl-certificate